# Can we use multiple delimiter in Mload teradata?

Tags: teradata, csv, mload

I have a file where I have multiple delimiters. I want to split based on delimeters and load it into a table in teradata. Please see below example:

```
38722719Ã‡I67.9Ã‡1Ç33984374Ç
47293377Ã‡Z11.51Ã‡1Ç37073044Ç
86809068Ã‡M54.2Ã‡1Ç49239923Ç
86811065Ã‡M54.2Ã‡1Ç49240429Ç
```

Here my two delimters are 'Ã‡' and 'Ç'

Whenever there is a single delimiter I have specified my delimiter in my mload script using 'format vartext'

FORMAT VARTEXT 'Ã‡'

But is there a way we can use multiple delimiters to split and load it into a table? I have tried separating the two delimiters with comma and it didn't work. Can you please throw some light?

Comment: Don't think so.  But I think you can specify one of your delimiters in mload, and then split on the other delimiter using `STRTOK` in the insert part of the script.  Or you could use sed to replace all occurences of  'Ç' with 'Ã‡'.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the info. I used _Sed_ command which easily resolved my problem.